# Flutter Firestore get Array from Geopoint >> Instance of 'GeoPoint' <<

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints

I've been getting this error ("Instance of 'GeoPoint) that I want to get the array list of the Geopoint from Firestore, I still don't know how to solve this, any help will be appreciated.

[Image from Firestore (Array List GeoPoint)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnzgj.png)

This is my Class Model to get all of the document from Firestore

```
class ModelLA{

  String nama, kode, alamat, creator, pass, foto;
  List<GeoPoint> titikLokasi;

  ModelLA.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data){
    nama = data['nama'];
    kode = data['kode'];
    alamat = data['alamat'];
    creator = data['creator'];
    pass = data['pass'];
    foto = data['foto '];
    titikLokasi = List.from(data['titikLokasi']);
  }

}
```

This is how do I get all of the data

```
 Firestore.instance.collection('LA').getDocuments().then((value){
      value.documents.forEach((element) {
        if (value.documents.isNotEmpty){
          value.documents.forEach((element) async {
            ModelLA modelLA = ModelLA.fromMap(element.data);
          });
        }
      });
```

Return error:

> [Instance of 'GeoPoint', Instance of 'GeoPoint', Instance of 'GeoPoint', Instance of 'GeoPoint', Instance of 'GeoPoint', Instance of 'GeoPoint']

Comment: please share your other code where you get `Instance of 'GeoPoint'`

Comment: @PeterHaddad done, I've already updated the post

Comment: This isnt an error, you saved instances of GeoPoint to the database and you are retrieving them, Are they getting added here `titikLokasi = List.castFrom(data['titikLokasi']);`?

Comment: @PeterHaddad Btw i already try to change from titikLokasi = List.castFrom(data['titikLokasi']); to data['titikLokasi'], and the error say 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes, you can see my image that I've been upload

Comment: How do you want `data['titikLokasi']` to be saved to `titikLokasi`?

Comment: @ShriHari the model is for to retrieve the data, not to update the database

Comment: Yeah, I mean to ask in which format it has to be stored. Instead of `[Instance of 'GeoPoint'']` Does it want to be [ [6.17535, 106.545] ]?

Comment: @ShriHari using this format List<GeoPoint>, Yes, you are right

Comment: `data['titikLokasi'].map( e => GeoPoint(e.getLatitude(), e.getLongitude()) );` Is something like this working out?

Comment: @ShriHari still not working:(

Comment: What do you get when you print(data['titikLokasi'])?

Comment: @ShriHari i get this: [Instance of 'GeoPoint', Instance of 'GeoPoint', Instance of 'GeoPoint', Instance of 'GeoPoint', Instance of 'GeoPoint', Instance of 'GeoPoint']

Comment: titikLokasi = GeoPoint.fromMap(data['titikLokasi']); how about mapping through it?

Comment: @Reign there is no GeoPoint.fromMap from the code

Answer (score 1):

I already find the solution to retrieve all of the data from GeoPoint list, thank you for everyone who helps me, this is how do i get the data:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('LA').getDocuments().then((value){
      value.documents.forEach((element) {
        if (value.documents.isNotEmpty){
          value.documents.forEach((element) async {
            ModelLA modelLA = ModelLA .fromMap(element.data);
            print('Data: ${modelLA.titikLokasi.map((e) =>
            print('lat: ${e.latitude} + long: ${e.longitude}'))}');
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

**Case closed**